# Composer no-dev still installing git repository

Tags: git, symfony, github, composer-php

I've an issue with `composer install`. I'm using the flag `--no-dev` to avoid installing all packages listed in the `require-dev` field of my composer.json.
It works quite well as I see all the unnecessary packages being removed, except one I defined by a GitHub repository. For some reason composer keeps trying to install it.
Note that I want to keep `repo_1` in prod, but not `repo_2`.

Given my config below, can you see any problem ?

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.103",
        "dragonmantank/cron-expression": "^2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "jms/i18n-routing-bundle": "2.*",
        "username/repo_1": "dev-branch",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.2",
        "jakub-onderka/php-parallel-lint": "^1.0",
        "username/repo_2": "dev-branch",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.11.8",
        "phpstan/phpstan-deprecation-rules": "^0.11.2",
        "phpstan/phpstan-doctrine": "^0.11.5",
        "phpstan/phpstan-phpunit": "^0.11.2",
        "phpstan/phpstan-symfony": "^0.11.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "7.4.4",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "slevomat/coding-standard": "^5.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.4",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@github.com:username/repo_1"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@github.com:username/repo_2"
        }
    ],
```

Thanks

PS: I'm using currently Symfony 3.4, I know it's an old version, don't worry I'm making the migration.

Comment: If you use `composer install`, the `composer.json` is not used, but `composer.lock`. Please add more details, like: which package got installed against your expectation

Comment: another explanation would be that repo_1 requires repo_2 in which case it being a dev dependency would be irrelevant.

Comment: @NicoHaase Well, I thought also that was due to the composer.lock, but all other packages in `require-dev` are not installed, unlike repo_2.
@Jakumi, I've checked and it's not the case. The two repo are independents from each other.